# Prevent Tomcat logging from going to stderr?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, stderr, java.util.logging

I currently have multiple web applications deployed in Tomcat which is running as a Windows service.  I created/modified most of the logging.properties files to (hopefully) create a separate log file for each web application.

My conf\logging.properties looks like:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix
= manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers
= 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level
= INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers
= 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level
= INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers
= 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for HTTP/2 handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for WebSocket handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE
```

Each of my web apps has the following logging.properties file int he WEB-INF\classes folder:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = prefix.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
```

I am currently logging everything within my web applications on the INFO level like so:

```
Logger.getLogger("LOG").log(Level.INFO, "Stuff to log");
```

Things seem to be relatively close to how I was hoping.  Stdout seems to be correctly going to the individual web application logs, but EVERYTHING also seems to be going to the tomcat8-stderr log as well.

I tried commenting out the ConsoleHandler from ALL config.properties, but I was still getting the same behavior.  How do I prevent everything from also being logged in the stderr log?

I added this to my Context.xml, but that did not seem to change anything:

```
<Context swallowOutput="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by setting the `Level` of my web application loggers to `FINE` and changing the web application ConsoleHandler level in logging.properties to `INFO`.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [Official Tomcat site](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Servlets_logging_API), the private package-renamed implementation of Apache Commons Logging namely JULI does have exceptions. the .handlers directive is defining the ROOT logger which in turn is the only possible output for calls that are coming directly from ClassLoader of common jars such as the StandardEngine ones or the java.sql driver ones. Unless a specific handler is assigned by class name after which a method call like java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger() could get potentially get a grip.

To use the so called "Facility specific properties" tomcat-juli features of per Engine, per Host and per Context log, the logging.properties in effect is the global tomcat logging configuration initially loaded at Engine startup :

> The calls to **javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...)** to write log
>   messages are handled by internal Tomcat logging. Such messages are
>   logged to the category named
>
> ```
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[${engine}].[${host}].[${context}]
> ```
>
> This logging is performed according to the Tomcat logging
>   configuration. **You cannot overwrite it in a web application**.

However,

> JULI [...] supports per classloader configuration, in addition to the regular global java.util.logging configuration. This means that logging can be configured at the following layers:
>
> 1. Globally. That is usually done in the `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties` file. The file is specified by the java.util.logging.config.file System property which is set by the startup scripts. If it is not readable or is not configured, the default is to use the ${java.home}/lib/logging.properties file in the JRE.
> 2. In the web application. The file will be `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`

So after making some various tests, I realized that **I was not able to reproduce your issue**, as I successfully logged from an application **exclusively and entirely** to the prefix.yyyy-mm-dd.log file defined in the per application `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`.

I say "entirely" taking into consideration that if the web application uses `System.out.print()`, the printed stuff will only show up in the "prefix."-files if `swallowOutput` is set to true in the context.xml (whether it be from the application's META-INF/context.xml or from the ${CATALINA_BASE}/conf/context.xml file.

Tweaking the logging levels to avoid the situation you where is not to my opinion an elegant bypass and I hope you have not settled down to that and will share your final resolution unless the problem vanished since !